# MappingException after upgrade to Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony

While upgrading my project from Syfmony 2.7.7 to Symfony 2.8, I always get the following exeption after a `php app/console cache:clear`:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
Class 'EasyUseserBundle\Entityser' does not exist
```

As a side note, FQN of entity is `EasyUse\UserBundle\Entity\User`.

Comment: Have a look at the [upgrade notes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md#yaml), maybe the issue with escaping the `backslash` character in YAML now.

Comment: I had a hardcoded class at YAML file hidden at one bundle.Thanks, if you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes where done on handling backslash `\` in YAML file if enclosed by double-quotes `"`.  The backslash must now be escaped.

Quote from [Upgrade notes for 2.8](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md#yaml)

> When surrounding strings with double-quotes, you must now escape \ characters. Not escaping those characters (when surrounded by double-quotes) is deprecated.

Before:

```
class: "Foo\Var"
```

After:

```
class: "Foo\\Var"
```

Comment: or `class: 'Foo\Var'` or even just `class: Foo\Var`.